# How do IDEs compile so quickly?

Tags: java, maven, ide

I have a legacy project I'm working on that takes 34 minutes to compile with Maven. But when I open it with my IDE (IntelliJ in this case), change something and run it it only takes a few seconds to compile. How does that happen? Does the IDE do differential compilation? If so can I do something similar with Maven?

Comment: Your IDE probably isn't recompiling the whole project, only the classes that have changed.

Comment: @Matt I figure there's something wrong there but I'm new to Maven so not sure how to bring down the compile time. Pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes IDEs only compile changed code. They also have custom compilers (e.g. ecj in eclipse) that don't require to compile the whole file.

Usually a `maven` run does not only consist of compilation. In the projects i handle most of the time is used for tests, and some additional for creating/bundling the artifacts.

To tell maven not to run the tests, you can add the `-DskipTests` command line option. Another option is to remove "`clean`" from your command line, so only changed files will be compiled.

*Keep in mind*: Before committing to source control, you should always run maven with clean and activated tests.